# Mono 3d Recostruction from Axes Detection?

Tags: 3d-reconstruction

Would a 3d reconstruction be possible from a single image if I manage to reliably detect lines in the target image which correspond to the 3 axes? I could also make sure I have a measured length along each of the axes, but it feels like it won't be enough.
The goal is to get a plausible model, it doesn't have to be extremely exact.

Comment: Basically, 3d could be decomposed (with-out losses, from the reconstruction point of view) in 3 distinct 2d_images (top, side, front), assume also some similarities.(maybe sometimes bottom and back needed : imagine a car). Guess what you can get from 1 image regardless of camera angle.(just a piece from model not enough for a fair reconstruction). Maybe you could simulate something in 3d but that model will be a fake, better said with a low level of matching with the real 3d object.

Comment: Say I only have though this one image, from a non-static camera in the same, known environment. Are there are further assumptions about the environment I could make to make it feasible?

Comment: Think better about the model (what you want to reproduce) and not the environment (placement is space). From the model you need to have lot's a similarities on all faces in order to made a good assumption of "what is to be put where not have additional image hints". For lengths, if images have part of all 3 "mandatory decomposition:top-side-front and having similarities on all faces" there are chances to have something maybe plausible (60-80%). Environment is good if want the real size, but also a smaller or bigger model have the same value compared with the real model.(proportionality)

Comment: Alright, so I guess this means I'd rather to my classification using computer vision. The idea was to combine a basic vision algorithm with my knowledge of the environment to simplify classification (in 3d space the task would be almost trivial). But it seems like this would be much more complicated than a proper vision algorithm. Thanks

Comment: Yes, something like, because you do not have all mandatory information from the model in 1 image.Something mandatory will always be missing regardless the angle.In the best scenarios you can make fair assumption only if you know ahead regarding "lot's" of similarities. Imagine a cube (trivial because only one parameter needed which is obvious even on 1 image) : in this case you could get 100% accuracy. An apple (simulate a sphere), but there : how much is green and how much red ? (is SnowWhite story or just a regular green apple)